# Setting time input to datetime from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

I'm currently retrieving data from a database over an API. The data comes back in this format:

```
2016-10-12T08:00:00
```

I would like to display the time portion of this in a time input field with AM and PM on my current webpage.

I have the following input:

```html
<input type="time" name="StartTime" class="form-control" />
```

When the ajax call finishes successfully to the api i do the following:

```js
$("#group-management #EditGroupModal [name=StartTime]").val(data.startTime);
```

data.StartTime is of course the string of datetime text seen above.

Which currently does not set the value of the time input on the page. I'm guessing it is because there is some formatting issue. I would like to parse the text string seen above and put it into the form field on the front end, but I am unsure of how to go about doing it. I have tried playing around with the Date object but no luck.

Comment: Is that time in your local zone or UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` input only accepts a time as a valid value, as in `08:00:00`

You can split your string, and pop of the time

```js
var data = {startTime : "2016-10-12T08:00:00"}

var time = data.startTime.split('T').pop();

$("[name=StartTime]").val(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" name="StartTime" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: But what about AM/PM?

Comment: @Feathercrown - what about it, the OP has a string with just `08:00:00`

Comment: Well, I'd imagine that string could change depending on what the server sends back; if it's after 12:59:59, you'd have to switch to PM.

Comment: Why, it's an ISO string, it goes all the way to 24, not everybody uses AM/PM, and the `time` input doesn't accept AM/PM either

Comment: From the question: "I would like to display the time portion of this in a time input field with AM and PM on my current webpage."

Comment: I actually didn't notice that. Then the answer is just **"no"**, you can't have AM/PM in a `time` input

Comment: Ah. Carry on then.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://momentjs.com/

```js
$(()=>{
  
 $('#StartTime').val(moment('2016-10-12T08:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<input type="time" name="StartTime" id='StartTime' class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this?:

```
var date = new Date('2016-10-12T08:00:00'); // replace the hardcoded time with your return value from Ajax call
$("#group-management #EditGroupModal [name=StartTime]").val(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
```

Comment: date.getHours() won't work, since it's a string that's returned. You could make a new date object with that string, though.

Comment: And what about PM?

Comment: this will produce completely different times in Chrum compared with Firefox and Edge

Comment: @JaromandaX - Probably doesn't matter for Firefox, as it doesn't support `time` inputs anyway